# How to disable a config file from CD server using Azure Deployment

Tags: azure, deployment

We are using Azure with Sitecore 8.0. I want to remove few config files(for e.g-all config files under ListManagement folder) which is already deployed in CD server. 
How to delete/disable config files under ListManagement folder using azure deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your System area of the master DB you should have items in roughly this location:

```
/sitecore/system/Modules/Azure/<Environment>/<Location>/<Farm>/<WebRole>/<AzureDeployment>
```

based on the template

```
/sitecore/templates/Azure/Deployment/Azure Deployment
```

On the item, go to the `Excludes` section. To exclude specific files use the 
`Deployment Type Exclude Files` or `Exclude Files` fields e.g:

```
App_Config\ListManagement\Sitecore.ListManagement.config;
```

Or to exclude an entire directory use `Deployment Type Exclude Directories` or `Exclude Directories` e.g.:

```
App_Config\ListManagement;
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Just reconfirming that this modification will remove all configuration related to List Management which are currently merged in CD server

Comment: See my edits above. I found there are other fields for excluding whole directories which is probably what you want to use (I'm not 100% sure that `Exclude Files` supports wildcards).

Comment: Thanks. We tried "Deployment Type Exclude Directories" using App_Config\ListManagement; and it worked :)

Answer (score 3):

We removed the List Management configuration by adding all List Management specific *.config* files to our project and replacing the content of the config files with the following:

```xml
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```